# Focal statistics means for very large area of NDVI raster to be used to extract value to points

Tags: r, ndvi, focal-statistics

I have tried using ArcGIS Pro running on server, NDVI from Living Atlas, and 30,000 points covering the entire eastern half of Colorado to get the mean NDVI mean value around each point for 270 meters
So far my software has crashed twice running focal statistics I need for the value extraction. I split my area in half to see if that helps and it's now been processing for 40 hours (at least it hasn't crashed yet).

Is there a method to derive the mean values around each point using R?

I still need to do the other half and really don't have 4 more days to get this one task done.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS is struggling to process a raster of this size. If you step out to R there are a couple ways to tackle this without actually processing the raster.

**These are the required libraries**

These packages do not come in the base distribution of R and must be installed. You can install these required packages and then add them into your R session using:

```
install.packages(c("sf","raster","exactextractr")) 
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(exactextractr)
```

**Here we create some example data representing points and a raster with the range of expected NDVI values.**

The function for reading in a shapefile is `st_read()` and for a single band raster is `raster()` You can pull up help for a function using the question mark eg., `?raster`.

```
suppressWarnings(
  pts <- st_centroid(st_cast(st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", 
                     package="sf")), "POLYGON")))
  pts <- st_transform(pts, crs="epsg:5070")

r <- raster(extent(pts), resolution=100)
  r[] <- runif(ncell(r), -1, 1) 

plot(r)
 points(st_coordinates(pts), cex=1, col="red")
```

You can ignore this code block since I am just creating example data. Your code would simply be: `r <- raster("myraster.tif")` and `pts <- st_read("myshp.shp")`

**Buffer points and extract raster values**

This is the crux of your analysis and is where we buffer the points and then extract the values, returning the mean. The dist argument in `st_buffer` specifies the buffer distance. I am adding a new ndvi column, containing the aggregated raster values, on the fly by piping the results of `exact_extract` directly to the spatial points object. Since we are extract values with a defined summary statistic the result is a numeric vector that matches the points so, can be directly related.

```
b <- st_buffer(pts, dist=1000)
  pts$ndvi <- exact_extract(r, b,  "mean") 
    pts

plot(pts["ndvi"], pch=20)
```

You can use `st_write` to write the 'pts' data out to a shapefile, or many other spatial data formats. Please read the help for exact_extract as there are many options, including weighted statistics using the fractional intersection of each raster cell. This will not be very relevant with the 0.5m resolution of your data but, is notable for future applications. I am recommend using this package because it is very fast and memory safe (there is an argument that controls the number of pixels read in). That said, you can actually avoid buffering the points by using the `raster::extract` function with the buffer argument and fun="mean". However, given your application I believe that this would be considerably slower than the option provided.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came down to not enough horsepower for the processing. Trying to process a 0.5 meter resolution raster (NDVI) over 55,000 sq miles (half of Colorado) against 50,000+ points with a lot of overlap just killed the server. I tried the divide and conquer through zonal statistics but too many extremely small slivers in the buffered points. The solution I finally ended up with was creating a fishnet grid over the area needing analysis, then converted to graphics. I then exported the raster portion of each grid and then combined groups of 30-50 tiles into new rasters which were then added to a mosaic. Since it was iterative, it was a perfect setup for python but couldn't read the NDVI raster values so I went manual - 177 grids.